# Run-time error '438': Object doesn’t support this object or property with GetOpenFilename

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

The following worked on my old installation of Outlook 2016 so it must be either a small typo or there is something wrong with the references.

The code is in Outlook 2016:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    'Open File to search
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(myFile) Then  '<~~ If user selects multiple file
        For i = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
            MsgBox myFile(i)
        Next i
    Else '<~~ If user selects single file
        MsgBox myFile
    End If
End Sub
```

I get:

[image: Error message]

for this line:

```
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
```

Here are my selected references:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your test working (In Outlook 365) by doing the following:

- Enable the `Excel Object Reference Library 16.0` in the VBE
- Create a variable and set it as `Excel.Application`
- Use this variable to qualify the `GetOpenFilename` method.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myApp As Excel.Application
    Set myApp = New Excel.Application

    'Open File to search
    myFile = myApp.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(myFile) Then  '<~~ If user selects multiple file
        For i = LBound(myFile) To UBound(myFile)
            MsgBox myFile(i)
        Next i
    Else '<~~ If user selects single file
        MsgBox myFile
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Be Aware

This creates a new instance of the Excel application for the duration your code is running.

Comment: 2 days i've been looking at this code and it just didn't make sense why it was not working. it is now working as i wanted it and for that i thank you.

Comment: @madmiddle as far as I can tell `GetOpenFileName` is a method for the **Excel Object Library**. Looking at the documentation for the methods/properties you want to use can generally steer you in the right direction :-)